# How to put a trailer clip in the middle of the main video with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, linux, concatenation

I have two videos of the same format encoded with the same codecs. I want **trailer.mkv** to be played after `n` minutes in the middle of **main.mkv**. After playing **trailer.mkv**, the rest of the **main.mkv** will continue playing. How can I concatenate them?

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do it in three steps.
Separate your main video.

Step 1. Trim the end.

`ffmpeg -i main.mkv -c copy -t 00:02:00 main-intro.mkv`

Step 2. Trim the start.

`ffmpeg -i main.mkv -c copy -ss 00:02:00 main-outro.mkv`

Step 3. Concatenate them with your trailer file.

`ffmpeg -safe 0 -i "concat:main-intro.mkv|trailer.mkv|main-outro.mkv" -c copy output.mkv`

You can write script and you will have opportunity to do it in one click.